# While using K-means, how do I represent IP addresses and languages on the coordinate axis?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm using K-means for unsupervised learning, using data vectors with an IP address and a language. I need to represent them in an abstract way, so that I can use this algorithm.

Comment: What is an _Ip_?  Do you mean _IP Address_?

Comment: Yes, an IP address. I should have explained it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data doesn't map in an obvious way onto vectors of continuous real numbers, don't use K-means.

To use [K-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) you need to have a well defined *distance* between any two points in the space.  To do that you need to have a notion of distance for each axis.

Typically discrete classifications like "language" don't have any natural mapping onto real numbers.

Comment: So, is there a way to make classification on problems of this genre? I have tought of PCA, but It's the same problem.